# how to create and use weighted metrics in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I want to make a weighted metric, and print it out as Keras trains my data. I however fail to find any working examples of how to do this.

When running:

```
metrics = [MyClass.MyWeightedMetric]
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop,loss="mean_squared_error",metrics=metrics)
```

where

```
class MyClass: 
    @staticmethod
    def MyWeightedMetric(y_true,y_pred,sample_weight=None):
        print(sample_weight)
        #do stuff that doesn't even use sample_weight for now
```

then it prints None all the time. If I change my compilation line into

```
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop,loss="mean_squared_error",weighted_metrics=metrics)
```

then I get the errors:

```
(0) Invalid argument: Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 16384
```

when calling model.fit(). It's not clear to me what I'm doing wrong or what I should be doing instead. I tried making a subclass as in this example https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric but that came with its own set of errors that I could not resolve.

Is there somewhere a working example of weighted metrics in keras, that I can provide at model compile stage? I find many examples of unweighted usages, but working weighted metric example seems impossible to find at the moment. For what it's worth, I'm using Tensorflow 2.0

Comment: Hi @Peter,  kindly provide minimum reproducible code and errors encountered.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `weighted_metrics` to `model.compile` during the training, the model expects a sample_weight column vector to compute the weighted metric. In your case, it seems like you are passing flatten tensor. The shape should be (16384, 1) instead of (16384). Further information
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#using_a_validation_dataset